# Highcharts - cannot force x axis to stop on a certain date

Tags: javascript, vue.js, highcharts

I am using highcharts/highstock and I send some data to the client.

I tried various sets of settings, but I cannot force x axis to stop on a certain date.

For example, I create a chart that has data from 20/3/2019 to 25/3/2019. The interval must always be 5 minutes.

The starting point is correct, it starts in 20/3/2019.

But the last point is always a day more. Its about 35 more points of 26/3/2019, instead of stopping at 25/3/2019.

*if this changes anything, the starting point should be 20/3/2019 00:00 , but it actually starts at 20/3/2019 03:00 in highcharts.

My data are

```
        { 
          time:{
            useUTC:false
          },
          boost: {
            enabled: true,
            allowForce:true,
            usePreallocated:true,
            useGPUTranslations: true
          },
          chart: {
            type: "line", 
            zoomType: 'x'
          },
          title: {
            text: item.title
          }, 
          xAxis: {   
            type: 'datetime', 
            tickInterval: 5 * 60 * 1000 , /*5 min */
            max: pointStop,
            labels: {
              format:'{value:%H:%M:%S}' 
            },
            dateTimeLabelFormats: {
              second: '%H:%M:%S',
              minute: '%H:%M',
              hour: '%H:%M',
              day: '%b. %e',
              week: '%b. %e',
              month: '%b. %y',
               year: '%Y'
             }
          },
          yAxis: {
            title: {
              text: item.title
            },
            alignTicks:'left', 
            textAlign:'left',
            align:'middle',
            opposite:false
          },     
          series: [
            {
              boostThreshold: 150,
              name: item.title, 
              pointStart: pointStart, 
              pointInterval: 5 * 60 * 1000,                  
              data: item.array,
              dataGrouping:{
                approximation: 'average',
                enabled:true,
                forced:true,
                groupAll:true,
                groupPixelWidth:20
              }
            }
          ]
        }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Hi @codebot, Could you reproduce that issue in some online code editor? You can start from: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/z68b2y79/

Comment: @ppotaczek Hi, please check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/pdnxhq9b/) out, even though the error is not reproduced here

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like an issue setting the tick count. The documentation states

> If a `tickAmount` is set, **the axis may be extended beyond the set `max` in order to reach the given number of ticks**. The same may happen in a chart with multiple axes, determined by chart. `alignTicks`, where a `tickAmount` is applied internally.

Comment: But I dont set any `tickAmount`. Should I set it?

Comment: Sorry I see that, can you attach a image of the chart ? Also what is pointStop defined as ?

Comment: I set `tickAmount` and nothing changed. I can attach an image, but how this can help you?

Comment: @codebot im trying to recreate your issue using highcharts demo https://jsfiddle.net/jm3on79v/ Does it look like this?

Comment: Try hard code `max: Date.UTC(2019, 3, 25, 0, 0, 0)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198829/discussion-between-riddell-and-codebot).

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable `oridinal` option, which is enabled by default in Highstock:

```
xAxis: {
    ordinal: false,
    ...
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6rqcLhp0/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.ordinal

Comment: Thanks, nice observation, but this did not solve either.

Comment: So what is the required result? Now the `xAxis` starts on `2019-5-1` and ends on `2019-5-9` as you wanted: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/36tcw2jk/